# Is there a Javascript/Lodash function to check if an object is missing ANY properties?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, lodash

I want to check a javascript object to see if any of it's properties are missing without checking each property individually.

I can use "hasownproperty" or do if/else statements to check if each one is null/undefined, I wanted a shorter way of checking an object.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+detect+missing+property+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting ***input*** and ***expected output*** using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You have to check each property individually because you want to know if each one is there. Are you asking how to do that with a collection of property names and/or validate against a given shape *(optionally with constraints)*?

Comment: So, `{ foo: 1, bar: null }` should say that the property `bar` is missing. However, what about `{ foo: 2 }` - should it say that `bar` is not present at all? If so, how are you to determine which properties are supposed to exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array::some()` on object values (get them with `Object.values()`) (this will return `true` if **ANY** property's value is `null` or `undefined`):

```js
const obj =  { a: null, b: 'there', c: 0, d: undefined };

console.log("Missing?", Object.values(obj).some(v => v === undefined || v === null));
```

If you want it the fastest possible, write your own function:

```js
const obj =  { a: null, b: 'there', c: 0, d: undefined };

function hasNullProperties(obj){
  for(const k in obj){
    if(obj[k] === undefined || obj[k] === null){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log("Missing?", hasNullProperties(obj));
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="10000000">

const obj =  { a: null, b: 'there', c: 0, d: undefined };

// @benchmark Array::some()

Object.values(obj).some(v => v === undefined || v === null);

// @benchmark custom func
function hasNullProperties(obj){
  for(const k in obj){
    if(obj[k] === undefined || obj[k] === null){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// @run
hasNullProperties(obj);

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```js
const hasMissing = obj => {
  const vals = Object.values(obj);
  return vals.filter(val => val !== null && val !== undefined).length !== vals.length
};  
const obj =  { "a":null, "b":"there", "c":0, "d":undefined }
console.log(obj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // so we cannot use that

console.log("Missing?",hasMissing(obj))
```